# Formal criterion of smoothness for analytic spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Does there exist a formal criterion of smoothness in the holomorphic category?

I'm looking for an analogue in the category of complex analytic spaces of the following theorem in the category of schemes over $\mathbb{C}$: a morphism of finite type schemes $f:X\to Y$ is smooth (i.e., flat with non-singular fibres) if and only if for every square zero extension of affine schemes (or Artin local rings) $S\to S'$, the map $X(S')\to X(S)\times_{Y(S)}Y(S')$ is surjective.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oui. For a map $f:X \to Y$ of complex-analytic spaces, $x \in X$ and $y=f(x)$, TFAE: (i) there are open $V \subset Y$ and $U \subset f^{-1}(V)$ with $y\in V$ and $x\in U$ so $U$ is $V$-isomorphic to a product of $V$ and an open ball, (ii)  $f$ is flat at $x$ and $X_y$ is a manifold near $x$, (iii) $\widehat{O}_{X,x}$ is a formal power series ring over $\widehat{O}_{Y,y}$.  See Thm. 3.1 in Seminaire H. Cartan, 1960/61 (vol. 13), Exp. 13 by Grothendieck. Via commutative algebra with (iii), it  follows that (ii) is equivalent to the infinitesimal criterion using infinitesimal analytic spaces.